# Display legend/value when hovering over raster layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, legend, popup, identify

Is there a way for this and how would I approach this? This would be in the normal map view and not in layout mode. It would be very hand if you have a lot of raster lays in one project and want to have a quick look over the values. 
I don't know if you could get the colors in the pop up?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the 'Value Tool'-plugin does the job? Go to Plugins – Manage and install plugins, and search for "value" in the All-tab. Click Install Plugin.
[image]

A Value Tool panel appears. Enable it and move your cursor over the raster image. The values will be be shown.

[image]

Comment: This is a good tool which I didn't know existed and I will use it for sure. But what I was looking for is something like, that you hover the mouse over the raster and it will display the legend (if it is possible). I was thinking I got a lot of raster layers in a project with ex 16 colors for every raster layer. Insteed of going to the layers and expand or right click to see the color scale, it would be good if you could just hover over the raster and get the legend.

Comment: Is there a plugin or any options so that you can display a legend in the map view/canvas?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Have you made a search (raster, value, legned etc.) in the plugins? I see Raster Tool, Several a.o.

Comment: In the View – Decorations several elements as grid, scale bar, north arrow are listet, but not legend...

Comment: I did but didn't find anything I was looking for. That would be realy good if decorations had that as an option :D